# Problems building hashmap java

Tags: java, json, string, hashmap

I'm in a little trouble building a hashmap but it took me a lot of time and I don't have a lot of experience with this kind of objects, my problem is when building the next hashmap:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>();
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map1 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();
Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

map2.put("one",1);
map1.put("two", map2);
map.put("cero", map1);

System.out.println(map);
```

The output is:

```
{cero={two={one=1}}}
```

But now I want to add another key `percent` with string value `10` at `cero` key level like:

```
{percent=10,cero={two={one=1}}}
```

I tried something like:

```
Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map3.put("percent", "10");
map.get("cero").putAll(map3);
```

There is an error in `putAll` method 'cause java needs a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` kind of object but I only need to add that `percent` property. Hope I'm clear with my question and you guys can help me, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you need `put` instead of [putAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map))

Comment: Also the `percent` has quite different `map` structure as `cero`.

Comment: It's not possible the way your are trying, that's what java type safety makes sure that you can't add anything else than the declared type. So, without changing map's declaration you can't go for it this way.

Comment: Why do you need a HashMap in a HashMap in a HashMap?

Comment: I cannot think of any situation where a map of strings to maps of strings to maps of strings to objects is a good design choice. Are you sure you can't redesign your system and code the relationships between objects differently?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify why I'm doing this, it's because I'm building a JSON output

Answer (score 0):

We can try to add map1 to map3

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> map = new HashMap<String, 
                                          Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map1 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>> 
                                                                                  ();
    Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map2.put("one",1);
    map1.put("two", map2);
    map3.put("percent", "10");
    map3.put("cero",map1);
    System.out.println(map3);
```

This gives following structure in map3
**{percent=10,cero={two={one=1}}}**